# Node Express parses request body with JSON incorrectly

Tags: node.js, express

I am sending a JSON object from web client, which looks like this:

```
{"AudioEncoder":{"Settings":{"1":{"audio_bitrate":"16000"}}}}
```

And in the request I get from `req.body.myvalue`:

```
{"AudioEncoder":{"Settings":[null,{"audio_bitrate":"16000"}]}}
```

In the Network panel of my browser I see correct value though:

```
myvalue[AudioEncoder][Settings][1][audio_bitrate]:16000
```

Error is where I am expecting object with key `{1:...` but get `[null:...`.

Any ideas why would this happen?

Comment: How are you retrieving that data? Do you use `JSON.parse`? or?

Comment: No, it comes as an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your browser isn't actually sending JSON, it's sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. This is not the correct value if you are trying to have the browser send JSON: `myvalue[AudioEncoder][Settings][1][audio_bitrate]:16000`. That's not JSON. Check the request headers for `Content-Type` and look at the raw body of the request to verify this. If you post your browser JS that's sending the AJAX, we can help you fix that. jQuery makes it a little tricky to specify the options correctly to get it to really send JSON.

Comment: Thanks, that's what it is!